# How to add Listbox / Select dropdown for shortcodes in WP 3.9 beta2 using TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

I need a list-box for shortcodes in visual editor. With WP 3.8 I got it working like :

```
            createControl : function(n, cm) {
            switch (n) {

    case 'example':
            var mlb = cm.createListBox('example', {
                title : 'Example Shortcode',
                onselect : function(v) {
                   tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.setContent(v);
                 }
            });

            // Add some values to the list box
    mlb.add('Shortcode', '[shortcode]Some Content Here[/shortcode]');

    // Return the new listbox instance
            return mlb;
    }
```

But these are not showing up in WP 3.9beta2. How to get it working?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Got it working with :      `editor.addButton('OwnStyling', {
    type: 'listbox',
    text: 'Stylesheet',
    icon: false,
    onselect: function(e) {
        editor.insertContent(this.value());
    },
    values: [
            {text: 'Menu item 1', value: 'Some text 1'},
            {text: 'Menu item 2', value: 'Some text 2'},
            {text: 'Menu item 3', value: 'Some text 3'}
    ],
    onPostRender: function() {
        // Select the second item by default
    }
});`

Comment: It would have been nicer if you posted the solution as a properly formatted answer and then mark it as accepted :)